# How to do method trace profiling using android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile, stack-trace

I have a trace file. I have Android Studio 3.5.2 installed.

Can anybody help me to do Method trace profiling using Android Studio?

Task:
Perform method profiling using a given trace file.